# Why is opening multiple files taking so long?

Tags: python, performance, file-io

I have a folder `foo` with thousands `.html` files about 300 Kb each. Here is what I do to open them:

```
import os
import time

folder_name = 'foo'
for file_name in os.listdir(folder_name):
    t = time.time()
    with open(os.path.join(folder_name, file_name)) as f:
        print(time.time() - t, 'seconds to open', file_name)
```

And here is the output I get:

```
1.6057319641113281 seconds to open 1.html
1.3181514739990234 seconds to open 2.html
1.1490132808685303 seconds to open 3.html
1.2970092296600342 seconds to open 4.html
1.0074846744537354 seconds to open 5.html
1.5122349262237549 seconds to open 6.html
1.1730327606201172 seconds to open 7.html
1.9992561340332031 seconds to open 8.html
```

etc.

I have an SSD and am quite surprised that it takes over a second to open a small file.

Is this normal? If not, what can be done to speed it up?

Comment: It doesn't look like it's even *reading* the files.  You're just opening them.  There's always IO overhead when accessing files, but you're not doing any meaningful work here.

Comment: BTW: there is `os.path.join(folder_name, file_name)` to create full path - it will use / for Linux/MacOS and \ for Windows (and : for old MacOS)

Comment: You're not even reading the files in this code, just opening them. I don't think this has anything to do with Python; something weird is going on with your filesystem or your hardware or something.

Comment: @Makoto: you're right, I changed "reading" to "opening". Opening is the slowest in what I'm doing, the rest is fast in comparison.

Comment: Are you sure you're just opening these files? No other processing? No imports that might have replaced `open` with a more expensive function?

Comment: @user2357112: No, I tested it with literally the same code as in the question.

Comment: Instead of printing the results in the opening loop, just store the file and timing amount in a list and print that out at the end. On possibility might be it's because of real-time virus protection running in the background. Maybe you should also try running it on another system if possible,

Comment: @martineau: I just tried that and the difference is not visible to the naked eye.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I was wrong. Since your time difference is calculated before `print()` is invoked, any slowness in `print()` shouldn't affect the calculated time (thanks to @DavidZ).

I could be wrong, but `print`ing the output can slow down your timing. To get a better idea, begin timing immediately before and immediately after you loop through the folder, e.g.

```
import os
import time

folder_name = 'foo'
t = time.time()
for file_name in os.listdir(folder_name):
    with open(''.join([folder_name, '/', file_name])) as f:
        # doing something with the files
print(time.time() - t, 'seconds to read entire folder')
```

Comment: `print` can easily invalidate naive benchmarks, but it's not going to cause a second of delay per line unless something seriously weird and expensive is going on with the output handling.

Comment: In the code from the question, the time difference is calculated before `print()` is invoked, so any slowness in `print()` shouldn't affect the calculated time.

Comment: Oh, that's true @DavidZ. I'll edit my response. Good thing I had that disclaimer, haha